# mysql transaction not commited Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

the model is simple i need delete 2 rows from tables the, the parcelas table have foreign key on deleted cascade, the assoc table doesnt have foreign key

the controller

```
  if($this->delete_model->delete_parcela_model($this->input->post('id_parcela_delete'),$this->input->post('id_loteo_delete'),$this->input->post('id_user_delete')))
        {
            echo 'deleted';
            exit(1);

        }
        else
        {
            echo 'error';
            exit(1);

        }
```

and the function call in the model  is

```
function delete_parcela_model($id_parcela,$id_pago,$id_user)
{

    $this->db->trans_begin();
    $this->db->query('delete from parcela where id_parcela = "'.$id_parcela.'" and id_dueno = "'.$id_user.'"');
    $this->db->query('delete from es_dueno_assoc where tipo_dueno_id = "'.$id_parcela.'" and user_id = "'.$id_user.'"');


    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
    {
        // generate an error... or use the log_message() function to log your error
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->trans_commit();
        return true;

    }
```

always return true but the transaction is not commited ....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why trans_status() isn't returning, but I would use the built in helper from the Codeigniter database helper like this and we can try and troubleshoot:

```
$this->db->delete($this->tables['parcela'], array("id_parcela" => $id_parcela, "id_dueno" => $id_user));
```

Then you can see test this by adding some logging so you can see what $this->db->affected_rows() is outputting:

```
var_dump($this->db->affected_rows());
var_dump($this->db->affected_rows() === FALSE);
die();
```

Then you can try getting the right value.  Also check [this](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/db_driver_reference.html?highlight=trans_status#CI_DB_driver::trans_status) page out for more detail.